# How to handle a Python (JSON) key error when I know the key exists?

Tags: python, json, key, keyerror

I'm trying to run the following code, I know the key "vin" exists, but keep getting a key error. How can I handle this within the code?

```
#page_url = 'https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/inventorylisting/viewDetailsFilterViewInventoryListing.action?zip=32805&inventorySearchWidgetType=PRICE&maxPrice=42500&maxMileage=50000&showNegotiable=false&sortDir=DESC&sourceContext=carGurusHomePageModel&distance=100&minPrice=0&sortType=PRICE&minMileage=0&sellerTypes=PRIVATE'

data = []
offset = 0
while True:
    print('Offset {}...'.format(offset))
    json_data = requests.get(page_url.format(offset)).json()
    
    for listing in json_data:
        jdata = requests.get(page_url.format(offset)).json()
        listing_title = listing['listingTitle']
        vehicle_id = listing['id']
        price = listing['price']
        year = listing['carYear']
        make_name = listing['makeName']
        model_name = listing['modelName']
        mileage = listing['mileage']
        vin = listing['vin']
        
        # ... other data

        #print((jdata, listing_title, vehicle_id, price, year, make_name, model_name, mileage, vin))
```

Comment: You are are getting a `KeyError`, then *the key doesn't exist*.

Comment: Can you share the content of `json_data`?

Answer (score 1):

Change the last line of your code to look like this:

```
try:
    vin = listing['vin']
except KeyError:
    print(f"'vin' not found in {listing}")
```

That will show you (1) that the key does not in fact exist in all of your data items, only *some* of them; and (2) how to handle this in the code.